# NotWhitelistedError(CUSTOMER_NOT_WHITELISTED_FOR_API) while uploading offline data using google AdWords API

Tags: java, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

I am new to Google Adwords.
I have completed all initial configuration and integration required to use Adwords API.
I have a test client account and I am able to get campaigns from that account. I also completed uploading offline data integration.

```
 // Upload offline data on the server and print some information.
    OfflineDataUploadReturnValue returnValue =
        offlineDataUploadService.mutate(operations.toArray(new OfflineDataUploadOperation[0]));
    offlineDataUpload = returnValue.getValue(0);
    System.out.printf(
    "Uploaded offline data with external upload ID %d, and upload status %s.%n",
    offlineDataUpload.getExternalUploadId(), offlineDataUpload.getUploadStatus());
```

But when I run the code to upload the data, I am facing below error:-

```
Request failed due to ApiException. Underlying ApiErrors:
  Error 0: NotWhitelistedError{apiErrorType=NotWhitelistedError, errorString=NotWhitelistedError.CUSTOMER_NOT_WHITELISTED_FOR_API, fieldPath=, reason=CUSTOMER_NOT_WHITELISTED_FOR_API, trigger=}
```

As I said earlier I am new to the Google AdWords, so any suggestion and help will be gladly appreciated. Thank you in advance!